# How to add timestamp on MySQL outputfile?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Hi I'm making an event that runs every minute and extracts certain columns on a table and creates an output-file in excel format

Since I cannot overwrite the file, i wanted to append a time-stamp on the filename so it will create unique excel filenames.

Here is the sample of my event

> CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `'Extract_Users'`
>
> ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Minute
>
> COMMENT 'Data Extraction' DO SELECT userID, email, id FROM table_one.user_name
>
> INTO OUTFILE 'C:\path\path\Desktop\test\user.xls'

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to my question. This works.

> DELIMITER $$
>
> CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS Extract_Users
>
> ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Minute COMMENT 'Extract_Users'
>
> DO
>
> BEGIN
>
> SET @sql_stmt := concat("SELECT userID, email, id FROM
>   user_table.user_info INTO OUTFILE
>   C:/path/path/desktop/test/Users-",DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d_%H%i%s'),".xls'");
>
> PREPARE extrct FROM @sql_stmt;
>
> EXECUTE extrct;
>
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE extrct;
>
> END $$
>
> DELIMITER ;